# PHP script stops running with 503 service unavailable

Tags: php, execution

I have my own PHP script to send a newsletter. It worked perfectly. Recently, my hosting provider points me out a quota to respect: 30 mails/minute. So, between each mail sending, I insert `sleep(2);`.

Since that change, after 5 minutes (300 seconds), the script stops and return:

> Service Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
>   Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Four observations.

1. At the beginning of my script, I put those two lines:

   ```
   ignore_user_abort(true);
   set_time_limit(0);
   ```

   So, the problem comes not from the max_execution_time variable (I verify: it is indeed modified).
2. The script works correctly on `localhost`, where the PHP ini variables are more limited than on my web host. So, the problem comes not from the `memory_limit` variable.
3. I thought it could be the Apache Timeout variable limit (300). But my host provider is skeptical about it...
4. The server works on PHP 5.5.

What could be causing this?

The script before (it works with PHPMailer) :

```
// all email addresses
while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    // ...

    if ($mail->send())
    {
        echo "success : " . $row["mail"] . "<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error : " . $row["mail"] . " - " . $mail->ErrorInfo . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

After :

```
// all email addresses
while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    ...

    if ($mail->send())
    {
        echo "success : " . $row["mail"] . "<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error : " . $row["mail"] . " - " . $mail->ErrorInfo . "<br/>";
    }

    sleep(2);
}
```

Comment: could you *include* the script that's not working...? we're not quite clairvoyant, yet.

Comment: I improved the formatting of your question to make it easier to read. Please review Stack Overflow's formatting documentation in the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so you can do this yourself next time. Note that code blocks inside a list need to be indented four spaces for each list level, plus an additional four spaces to indicate a code block.

Answer (score 2):

I think on the server mod_fastcgi or equals are used.

Have a look at this old post http://www.binarytides.com/php-set-time-limit/

> For example mod_fastcgi has an option called "-idle-timeout" which controls the idle time of the script. So if the script does not output anything to the fastcgi handler for that many seconds then fastcgi would terminate it. The setup is somewhat like this:

```
Apache <-> mod_fastcgi <-> php processes
```

You should use a queue and an crontab, which the queue processed once per minute.

Hope this helps.

Comment: At each mail sending, the script outputs the mail address... So, there is no inactivity (idle time), isn't it ? Apache is being run on my server via lsphp (litespeed).

Comment: I have not used lsphp yet. Works the execution of the script from the command line like   
`php send_mails.php`.

Comment: I tested "rengaw83" solution. After 5 minutes, still an interruption... Actually, it's not litespeed, but mod_lsapi. There is no apache limitations, so my host provider (they deleted all apache limitations)... I will try the command line.

Comment: Your question edit looks like, you fetch the addresses from an db. The easiest way are, you add a new column `dispatched` or whatever. On the fetch from the db you add `WHERE dispatched != 1` and `Limit 0, 30` to the query. so you get only 30 Entries per run. After the mail has send, you has to update the `dispatched` flag for the db entry to 1. So you have an simply queue which can be scheduled by a crontab or what ever you want.

Comment: Sure? The sending of only 30 mails takes about 5 minutes or longer? 
I dont think so. 

If the Server/FPM could not be configuret to run longer, you has to run the script by cli ore better you should send only 30 mails per cron run and the cron should run every minute.

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't clear. It works yet, but the initial 5min interruption is still a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem.

This might help someone ellse, not a direct answer to given question.

2 methonds inside a class were calling eachother.

```
function method1(){
     method2();
}

function method2(){
    method1();
}
```

It was little more complicated than this example

Was expectig different error in this situation tho...

Comment: What makes you think that this is the problem here? If it was, how could the script work properly before adding `sleep`?

Comment: @NicoHaase did you read my answer? I wrote `This might help someone ellse, not a direct answer to given question.`

Comment: If this is not a "direct answer", why did you post it as a direct answer?

Comment: @NicoHaase Since I've had the same status code, I googled it and I was redirected to this thread but I could not get my answer. So I thought other people might be searching for the same issue that I've had, open this thread and they would see their answer.

Answer (score 0):

This could really be a number of things, even file permissions. I would first undo your change and see if its working again. If not, then you know its not the sleep() command thats causing the problem. If it is the sleep command, the issue might have something to do with a timeout while waiting for php to respond. Try sleeping for .1 seconds instead, just to test if it works.